# Flask: how to get json with specific id

Tags: json, http, flask, crud, put

I am getting involved with flask, and need some help with routing.
I want to create an API for developers, which can give json responses, depending on  the get-requests.
This is working already:

> @app.route("/jsonusers") def jsonusers():
>       resp = app.response_class(
>       response=json.dumps(users),
>       status=200,
>       mimetype='application/json'

```
)
```

reponse: all users.

How can I have access to specific users:
1) get them (something like: /jsonusers/{user-id}
2) update user (Put-Method: like /jsonusers/{user-id}/update?name=smith&e-mail=smith@gmail.com

Maybe you can also recommend a nice frontend-Framework working nicely with Flask (Angular?)

Thanks community
Hans

Answer (score 0):

If you need to acces data from a get or post call. you can do this:

```
@app.route("/jsonusers/<user_id>")
def jsonusers(user_id):
//then you can acces it by the name user_id



 @app.route("/jsonusers",methods=["get","post"])
   def jsonusers():
   user_id = request.args["user_id"]
   //here your call would be something like http://url:port/jsonusers?user_id=the_id_of_the_user
```

Angular and boostrap works fine with jinja and flask so no problem